# Could not find class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout',

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

> Could not find class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout',
>   referenced from method com.example.slid.MainActivity.onCreate

I am unable to resolve this issue, my libraries are updated.

Comment: Extend FragmentActivity of android.suport.v4.widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class is in the `support-v4` and `support-v13` libraries in [the Android Support package](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res).